# Status bar shows same icon twice

Tags: wifi-hotspot, notification-bar, notification-icons

When I switch on Hotspot,  the status bar shows the Hotspot ON icon at two places,  near the clock and on the left side too.  I'm running Cyanogenmod 12.1 with Android Lollipop 5.1

Comment: Are you using a nightly or a stable build? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: It's a stable build and I don't see option to post screenshot as I'm using Stack Exchange android app, not the website

Comment: You take a screenshot by holding power and volume up buttons.

Comment: I know how to take a screenshot,  I'm saying that this app doesn't have a UPLOAD picture function

Comment: You can use a website or an app that supports sharing/uploading pics from the device. Then share the link with us. Also, please use @ followed by the user's name to notify him.